# Allow files to be listed when viewing a directory but protected (via HTTP authentication) when accessed directly

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, permissions, .htaccess, htpasswd

I created a password protected directory using `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`, but the files don't show up when I go to the directory URL.

I have this in my `.htaccess`:

```
#Protect multiple files
<FilesMatch "^(.*).csv$">
AuthName "Dialog prompt"                                                                                                                                                                                       
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /xxxxx/test                                                                                                                                              
#AuthUserFile ".htpasswd"                                                                                                                                                                                      
Require valid-user                                                                                                                                                                                             
</FilesMatch>
```

[image: Directory listing - not showing the CSV files]

**UPDATE:** I'm protecting the CSV files in that directory. They disappear from the directory listing when that auth directive is set. They show up when I remove it. I want to be able to at least see the files in the directory listing, but when accessing these files it would offer an auth prompt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to configure apache to view hidden (\`.\`) files?](https://serverfault.com/questions/245922/how-to-configure-apache-to-view-hidden-files)

Comment: "when I goto _the_ URL" - What URL? You have your mod_auth... directives in a `<FilesMatch "^(.*).csv$">` container, but from your screenshot you would seem to be requesting a directory? Please explain exactly what you are trying to protect, what request(s) you are making and what the expected outcome is?

Comment: I'm protecting the CSV files in that directory. They disappear when that auth directive is set. It shows up when I remove it. I want to be able to at least see the files, but when accessing these files it would offer a auth prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm protecting the CSV files in that directory. They disappear when that auth directive is set. It shows up when I remove it. I want to be able to at least see the files, but when accessing these files it would offer a auth prompt.

When a directory listing is generated using mod_autoindex, an internal subrequest is issued for each file that appears in the directory listing. When using a `<FilesMatch "^(.*).csv$">` container then it is also being processed for these subrequests and consequently the entry of these files in the directory listing is also blocked.

An alternative to using the `<FilesMatch>` directive is to use an `<If>` expression and test against `THE_REQUEST` server variable instead. This is then only *successful* when the `.csv` files are actually requested by the user and not when browsing the directory listing.

For example:

```
# Directory listings (mod_autoindex) need to be enabled
Options +Indexes

# Protect CSV files from being accessed, but still visible in directory listing
<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#\.csv(\s|\?)#">
AuthName "Dialog prompt"                                                                                                                                                                                       
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /xxxxx/test                                                                                                                                              
Require valid-user                                                                                                                                                                                             
</If>
```

`THE_REQUEST` contains the first line of the HTTP request. eg. `GET /foo/test.csv HTTP/1.1` (in the case of a GET request for `/foo/test.csv`) - and does not change throughout the request. So when requesting the directory itself, eg. `/foo/` then the enclosed block is not processed and the listing of these files are not blocked.

The added complication is that `THE_REQUEST` contains the entire URL as requested, which could include a query string. So, the check for `(\s|\?)` (ie. whitespace *or* a literal `?`) is to avoid the password check being bypassed by simply including a query string. eg. `/foo/test.csv?anything`.